# Going from 2nd form back to the first form in the same instance

Tags: c#

I have a program that consists of two winforms and three classes, one of which is static.  My first form does some work and has a button that opens the second form.  When the second form opens, the first one closes via this.Visible = false.

I have a button on the second form that I want to take me back to same instance of the first form so that I can input more information if needed.  Any new information would have to be added to the original information so that I can go back to the second form.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried instantiating a new form but of course the previous values were gone.

Here is the code for my first form to open the second:

```
//event handler to call Daily Summary form
    private void btnDailySummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DailySummaryForm form2 = new DailySummaryForm(); 
        this.Visible = false;
        form2.Show();            
    }
```

Here is the code for my second form to reopen the first:

```
private void btnRtnToOrderMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {             
        //closes Daily Summary form
        this.Close();
    }
```

I tried doing "OrderForm.Visibile = true" but of course without instantiating a new instance that doesn't work.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Form2, you can pass in a reference to Form1 in the constructor.

So Form2 constructor:

```
public Form2(Form form1)
{
     //Do stuff with form1, such as store reference to use later
}
```

And then when you create Form2 in Form1, you can do this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Comment: I made the appropriate changes but maybe I've been staring at my monitor too long today because I am still confused.  When I press the button for form 2 to close, the program goes to the event handler, not the constructor.  If I add "this.Visibility = true" to the constructor, how do I get the event handler to jump up there and execute the statement?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways, but here is one that I like the design of:

```
private void btnDailySummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DailySummaryForm form2 = new DailySummaryForm(); 
    this.Visible = false;
    form2.Show();
    form2.Closing += (sender, args) =>
    {
      this.Show();
    }
}
```

(Note: this is all offhand; may need minor syntactical fixes to compile).

This way form2 doesn't need to know about form1 at all, it just knows that someone else wants to run some code when it gets closed.  Form1 on the other hand is able to tell form2, open me when you're done.  The most common/trivial example is to just pass the instance of Form1 around (as another answerer has already proposed) but this exposes everything about Form1 to Form2, allowing it to do a lot of things that you might not want.  It also increases the coupling between the two forms (meaning you can't use one without the other).

Comment: Can you explain the line form2.Closing += (sender, arggs) =>.  I'm unsure of what is going on there.  I've never even seen => before.  What does that do?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie It's attaching an event handler.  Form has a lot of events, one of them is `Closing`.  It means, "execute the method that I'm about to provide when you are "Closing".  The rest of it is just wrapping a call to `this.Show()` in an annonomous function so that the signature will be correct.  The event needs to be given a method with two parameters, the sender and EventArguments; we don't need them, but we still need to have them there so that everything compiles.  There are other more robust synaxes for attaching a handler to an event if you prefer them.

Answer (score 0):

Does Form2 need to keep the old information when you go back to form1? If so, then you need to make sure that, when you reopen Form2, you are not creating a new object.

```
DailySummaryForm form2;

private void btnDailySummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if(form2 == null) //Check for null ...
        form2 = new DailySummaryForm(); //..and create new Form2 if it is null.
    this.Visible = false;
    form2.Show();            
}
```

This way, when you re-open Form2 after the first time, the old information will still be there and then you could simply add the new information.

At this point, it'd be best to create some sort of event in Form1 that, when raised, causes something (such as an update) to happen in Form2.

Otherwise, if you do not need to keep the old information, feel free to dispose of Form2 when you switch back to Form1 and simply pass the new version of the information from Form1 into Form2 using a constructor like others have suggested.

Comment: No, the information displayed in form 2 is derived from the information in form 1 so any changes in form 1 makes that instance of form2 useless.  So I plan on just using this.Close() to close form2 all together.

Comment: So then what exactly are you trying to do between the two forms since it doesn't matter if Form2 is perserved? Do you want Form2 to pass information that it changed back to Form1?

Comment: No, form 2 gets its information from form1.  I just want to go back to the same instance of form1 in the case I have to input more information.  If I need form2 again, I'll re-click the button on form1 and a new form with the updated information will be generated.

Comment: In that case, in Form1, create a new eventHandler like "form2.FormClosing += form2_Closing;" and then create a method in Form1 named "private void form2_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)" and in that method put the logic "this.Visible = true". This is basically what Servy told you to do, but his way of using lambdas and anonymous functions is a bit advanced.

Comment: Forgot to add that form2.Closing += form2_Closing should be declared before you invoke form2.Show();